# Ember 2.1.0 not working in IE11 on Windows 7

Tags: ember.js

My Ember 2.1.0 app works fine in dev mode in Chrome and Safari on my Mac. But in IE11 on Windows 7 I get a white page with absolutely no warnings in the console.

Is this a known issue?

Comment: Maybe check security settings or try with other Ember versions so you can narrow the issue.

Comment: You mention the console - what do you see in Ember Inspector?

Comment: How are you serving your app?

Answer (score 0):

This isn't really answer but I don't have enough reputation points to comment. I ran into a similar situation with an ember app and IE 11 - white screen, app wouldn't load. Fortunately I'd done frequent check ins was able to go back to the one that broke it. The issue was a duplicate variable declaration in a component.
(showValidationErrors: false, was added twice) Removing this fixed the problem. Bottom line is that IE is seems to be way more picky about things like this than Chrome or Firefox and all (most, ok some...) of those errors the cli spits out during a build are important.